# How to speed up nested for loop in R for large data, which currently uses append in it and outputs large lists? How to vectorise?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vector, append

Hopefully I get this right this time around, previously I posted (although that was years ago) and I remember that I didn't have much of a good example/ detail in my question.

So, I'm using the quakes dataset in R, for this example to hopefully make it easier to follow.

Hopefully this example is clear.

I have a function myfunc:

```
    myfunc <- function(x,y){
      z <- (x - y)^2
      return(z)
    }
```

So what I'm trying to do, is use this function for each and every row in the Quakes dataset. So for example using the head of the dataset:

```
> library(datasets)
> data(quakes)
> head(quakes)
     lat   long depth mag stations
1 -20.42 181.62   562 4.8       41
2 -20.62 181.03   650 4.2       15
3 -26.00 184.10    42 5.4       43
4 -17.97 181.66   626 4.1       19
5 -20.42 181.96   649 4.0       11
6 -19.68 184.31   195 4.0       12
>
```

this first row would use the `myfunc` function with every other row in the dataset and then the same would happen with the second row for every other row in the dataset etc.

I'm currently using the following nested for loop and appending to a vector. I then `cbind` them all together.

```
lat <- vector()
long <- vector()
depth <- vector()
mag <- vector()
stations <- vector()
for (i in 1:6){
  for (j in 1:6){
    lat <- append(lat,(myfunc(quakes$lat[i], quakes$lat[j])))
    long <- append(long,(myfunc(quakes$long[i], quakes$long[j])))
    depth <- append(depth,(myfunc(quakes$depth[i], quakes$depth[j])))
    mag <- append(mag,(myfunc(quakes$mag[i], quakes$mag[j])))
    stations <- append(stations,(myfunc(quakes$stations[i], quakes$stations[j])))
  }
}
final <- as.data.frame(cbind(lat, long, depth, mag, stations))
```

The actual data I'm doing this on, has 1244 rows and 13 columns, and doesn't seem to run the full code (or takes too long, as I usually just stop when it's nearing 1 hour). I have tried my normal code on 191 rows and that seems to run fine, within 1 minute usually.

I've read up online about this and it's clear that the append is not good to do in for loops. I've come across `sapply`, vectorisation and some examples. However I'm really struggling to get this to work and output the exact same that it does currently.

I was wondering whether anyone has anyone can help me out with this/ has useful advice?

Thank you.

Update: Just to add that I'm going to be using the cbind function to bind two columns onto the results. For example if the quakes data had a letter assigned to each row i.e. A, B, C I would want the final output after the cbind to show from this

```
 ID    lat   long depth mag stations
1 A -20.42 181.62   562 4.8       41
2 B -20.62 181.03   650 4.2       15
3 C -26.00 184.10    42 5.4       43
4 D -17.97 181.66   626 4.1       19
5 E -20.42 181.96   649 4.0       11
6 F -19.68 184.31   195 4.0       12
```

to

```
 ID1 ID2   long depth mag stations
1  A   A  (row from final)
2  A   B  (row from final)
3  A   C  (row from final)
4  B   A  (row from final)
5  B   B  (row from final)
6  B   C  (row from final)
```

etc.

Currently I'm using something similar to this:

```
ID1 <- vector()
ID2 <- vector()
for (i in 1:1244){
  for (j in 1:1244){
    ID1 <- append(ID1,quakes$ID[i])
    ID2 <- append(ID2,quakes$ID[j])
  }
}
```

It currently returns large character lists. Do you have suggestion on how this could be improved?

Apologies for not mentioning this in my original post.

Comment: Thanks Rui, I've tried to put that in place of the image. Hope that's okay?

Comment: Sorry, `quakes` is a built-in data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two functions.
The first is my original answer made a function.According to a comment it's already faster than the original in the question but the second function is around twice as fast. It is also more memory efficient.

```
myfunc <- function(x, y){
  z <- (x - y)^2
  return(z)
}


slower <- function(X, fun = myfunc){
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  res <- sapply(X, function(x) {
    o <- outer(x, x, fun)
    o[row(o) != col(o)]
  })
  as.data.frame(res)
}

faster <- function(X, fun){
  f <- function(x, fun = myfunc){
    y <- lapply(seq_along(x), function(i){
      fun(x[i], x[-i])
    })
    unlist(y)
  }
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  res <- sapply(X, f, fun = fun)
  as.data.frame(res)
}
```

Test both, the results are identical.

```
res1 <- slower(quakes, myfunc)
res2 <- faster(quakes, myfunc)
identical(res1, res2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Now for the timings with package `microbenchmark`.

```
library(microbenchmark)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  outer = slower(quakes, myfunc),
  fastr = faster(quakes, myfunc),
  times = 10
)
print(mb, unit = "relative", order = "median")
#Unit: relative
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
# fastr 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10  a 
# outer 1.545283 1.650968 1.970562 2.159856 2.762724 1.332896    10   b


ggplot2::autoplot(mb)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - this works great and outputs what I need. This was almost twice as quick for my dataset which has 191 rows. However I'm still facing the same issue with the dataset  with 1244 rows. I've stopped running it as it seems to take too long. I've had a search and it seems like it's the outer function, even though this is wayyy quicker than before. It still takes longer for the larger table. Do you have any further advice for improvements? Greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: @cardboard12 I've added a new method, see the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rui Barradas, that is much clearer to see the difference. Sorry I forgot to mention that I took out the filter from the slower function i.e. o[row(o) != col(o)] to get the output I need. So have updated the faster function, for the [-i] to [-192] to get what I need for now. Although this is slightly quicker for the 191 rows. I'm still having issues running the 1244 rows one. I've never really calculated on anything this big in R before. So am not sure how long I should be waiting for it to run? Is near 1 hour normal? I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: My cbind does bind two columns onto the results from faster. Both of these a Large character types in R (around 5.8mb). I though R could handle these? Am I wrong? Very grateful for your help on this - thank you

Comment: @cardboard12 The way you are doing it is very slow. You create `ID1 <- vector()` (and the same for `ID2`). Then in the loop keep extending theses vectors. This calls R's memory management routines *every* time through the loop. Create `ID1 <- numeric(1244)` and then `ID[i] <- quakes$ID[i]`.

Comment: Thanks @Rui I have tried this just now, however I need the variable to repeat. I.e. A would need to repeated 1244 times and against each row there would be a different _second_ ID. I'll have a look into the rep function, that might help. But grateful if you have a quicker way of doing this.

Comment: Just to update for completeness, the update made earlier with the two vectors created in a loop for ID columns. Have fixed this by using the following 
ID1 <- vector()
ID1 <- vector()
ID1<- rep(quakes$ID, each = 1244)
ID2 <- rep(quakes$ID, times = 1244)
Thanks a lot Rui for your help with this. I've managed to get the large dataset to run in <1 min when it wasn't even completing before. I really appreciate your help on this. Thank you!